# VisualStudio Code shortcut key for switching debugging task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or combination of keystrokes) that would let me switch tasks on this toolbar in VS Code?

[image]

or this one?

[image]

Alternatively, is there a better workflow for debugging shared client/server code that requires two debugging sessions than doing it all in one view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 2: In v1.70 Insiders now there is a new command for switching debug sessions:

```
Debug: Select Debug Session
workbench.action.debug.selectDebugSession
```

It is unbound to a keybinding by default.

It brings up a quick pick panel of running debug sessions plus the option to `Start a new debug session` which when chosen displys the available launch configurations.

---

Update: According to this issue commands are being added to switch debug consoles.  May be in vscode v1.69.  See
[add keyboard shortcuts to navigate debug consoles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151772#issuecomment-1167734917)

> Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> on mac) to move to the previous
> console. The command `Debug: Focus Previous Debug Console` should do
> the same thing.
>
> Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on mac) to move to the next console.
> The command `Debug: Focus Next Debug Console` should do the same
> thing.

---

Previous answer

I don't think there is an easy way to switch debug sessions by keystroke yet.  See [UI Issues with two simultaneous client/server debug sessions, switching debug sessions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136617): issue is a backlog candidate, upvote it.  Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39560 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108844.

In the meantime, for my extension upon request by a user I created a command to go to the next or previous debug session, see https://github.com/ArturoDent/launch-config/issues/11#issuecomment-1013606260 - but since there is no real supported way to do so it is a bit of a hack but does work.

Outside of my extension you can package the commands yourself via a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

Try these keybindings:

```
{
  "key": "alt+k",      // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.debug.action.focusCallStackView",
      "list.selectAll",
      "list.collapseAll",
      "list.focusPageDown",       // focus next debug session
      "list.select"
    ]
  },
},

{
  "key": "alt+i",      // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.debug.action.focusCallStackView",
      "list.selectAll",
      "list.collapseAll",
      "list.focusPageUp",       // focus previous debug session
      "list.select"
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: Upvoted!  Just 18 more votes needed!

Comment: Seems unlikely, I just added two more related github issues that didn't go anywhere.  One of them has a version of the keybindings I showed above.  Give them a try.

Comment: They do the trick!  Unless a better answer comes along in the next day or two, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I changed focusPageDown to focusDown and focusPageUp to focusUp so that it would work with more than two sessions.